# Search Bar gap when searching

Tags: swift, ios8, tableview, searchbar

I don't know why, but I'm getting a gap between the search bar and the results, as if the scope buttons are showing, only they're not.

In the image, the highlighted view is UISearchBarContainerView and the bordered view is UITableViewWrapperView

Image: http://blog.minetheapp.com/wp-content/uploads/searchgap.jpg

Here's the code to create the search bar:

```
// set up results controller
let resultsController = SearchResultsController()
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultsController)

// set up search bar in article table
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
searchBar.placeholder = "Procurar Artigo"
searchBar.sizeToFit()

articleTable.tableHeaderView = searchBar
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = resultsController
```